# Is a direct sum of two commutative rings still commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is a direct sum of two commutative rings still commutative?

Comment: Do you know how the direct sum is defined?!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Since multiplication is defined term-wise, commutativity of $\mathcal{F}\oplus\mathcal{G}$ follows from the commutativity of each component.

Comment: suppose f is in F, g is in G. why fg=gf?

Comment: For the reason written above, $f,g\in\mathcal{F\oplus G}$, which is commutative. Hence, $fg=gf$.